# How do I put text above and under an expression?

Tags: overset, raise

I'm trying to outline something in a function, by putting text under and above the equation. Text under the equation works fine, but the text above the equation is moved to the right of the equation, which is maybe normal for powers, but I hoped it would behave the same as how it works for sum signs.

```
\begin{align} 
\Big\langle \hat{A}(t) \Big\rangle_S &= \int U_m^*(\vec{r}) \hat{H}     U_n(\vec{r}) \dd^3 r
\\& = \displaystyle\Big\langle 
\underset{\text{\color{darkgreen}Time independent}}{\displaystyle
    {\displaystyle{\color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}} 
        \color{black}\Big| 
        \color{darkgreen}\underbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\hat{A} \Big|}
        \color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}
    }\displaystyle^{\text{\color{red}Time dependent}}
} \Big\rangle
\end{align}
```

[image: I want to point out a few terms in this equation]

I also thought that maybe there was a thing that works similar to `\underset`, but then puts the text above the equation. I tried both `\overset` and `\stackrel`.

````
```
\begin{align} 
\Big\langle \hat{A}(t) \Big\rangle_S &= \int U_m^*(\vec{r}) \hat{H}     U_n(\vec{r}) \dd^3 r
\\& = \displaystyle\Big\langle 
\underset{\text{\color{darkgreen}Time independent}}{\displaystyle
\stackrel{\text{\color{red}Time dependent}}{
    \displaystyle{\color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}} 
    \color{black}\Big| 
    \color{darkgreen}\underbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\hat{A} \Big|}
    \color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}
}
} \Big\rangle
\end{align}
````

It does (somehow) print the same output as shown above, but it gives me an error message. For `\overset`:

```
Limit controls must follow a math operator.
\overset ...nrel@@ {\mathop {\kern \z@ #2}\limits 
                                              ^{#1}}
```

as well as for `\stackrel`:

```
Limit controls must follow a math operator.
\stackrel #1#2->\mathrel {\mathop {#2}\limits 
                                          ^{#1}}
```

I have no clue what that means, or how I should write the code so that it does the thing I want. Also, does anyone know where `\overset` and `\stackrel` are useful for, as it apparently can't do the thing I want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I did find the way to do what I want using \raisebox, but I didn't find where \overset is used for.

```
\\& = \displaystyle\Big\langle 
\underset{\text{\color{darkgreen}Time independent}}{\displaystyle
    \raisebox{20pt}{\parbox{0cm}{\text{\footnotesize\color{red}Time dependent}}}{
        \displaystyle{\color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}} 
        \color{black}\Big| 
        \color{darkgreen}\underbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\hat{A} \Big|}
        \color{red}\overbracket[1.2pt]{\color{black}\psi_S(t)}
    }
} \Big\rangle
```

[image: An equation with a few terms pointed out.]

Oh and usage of `\footnotesize` will ensure that it's roughly the same size as the text under the equation.